# Boundedness in Function Spaces

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, function-spaces

Let $(C(I),d_\infty)$ be a metric space, where $C(I)$ is the set of all continuous functions on a closed interval $I$ and $d_\infty=\sup_{x\in I}\{|f(x)-g(x)|\}$.

I am reading a book about real analysis and I am new to the subject. So I am not very familiar with function spaces. My question is: if there is a subset $K\subset C(I)$ and if $K$ is bounded can I say that the family of functions $f\in K$ is uniformly bounded (i.e. there is a constant N such that $\sup_x |f(x)|\leq N, \ \forall f\in K)$ as well? How about the converse?

Comment: What does bounded mean to you for a set to be bounded in $C(I)$? That should help answer your question.

Comment: @cmk The definition is K is bounded if there exists $r > 0$ such that for all $f$ and $g$ in $C(I)$, we have $d(f, g) < r$, so they should be equivalent I think. Is that correct?

Comment: Correct! $\ \ $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you stated , if your closed interval is compact (which it is if $I$ is bounded) then you have (I will go ahead with the definition you gave in the comments)
Assuming your $K$ is nonempty, pick a fixed function $g\in K$ and observe that $\exists M$ such that $ |g(x)|\leq M$ for all $x\in I$.(since $I$ is compact), therefore by triangle inequality, we have for all $f\in K$,
$|f(x)|\leq |f(x)-g(x)|+ |g(x)|\leq r+M$. Take supremum to obtain the desired conclusion of uniform boundedness.

For the converse, assuming the uniform boundedness, just observe (again by triangle inequality)
$|f(x)-g(x)|\leq \sup_{x\in I}|f(x)|+\sup_{x\in I}|g(x)| \leq N $ for some $N$, so taking supremum would  give you, $d_{\infty}(f,g)\leq N $ for any two functions $f,g\in K\implies K$ is bounded.

Lastly, if $I$ is not bounded eg. $I=[0,+\infty )$ then such conclusions are not true. Just take the trivial example $K=\{ x,x+1\}$ to be two point set and observe none of the functions are bounded although $K$ is.
I hope this answers your question $\ldots $